# Using DPDA instead of LR parsers

Tags: context-free, compilers, parsers

If LR parsers handle only DCFLs than why we don't just use dpda to parse these languages? What are advantages of using LR parsers over DPDA? Is it that it is easy to built autonomously or something else?

Comment: Because it's easier to write (and read) a grammar than a DPDA?